# Error:The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</application>"

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chawlaz.contentprovider"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chawlaz.contentprovider.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.provider.College"
            android:name="StudentsProvider"/>
    </ provider >
</ application>

</manifest>
```

Its showing an error in manifest tag which is already closed.
also:
Error:Cannot read packageName from /home/chawlaz/Downloads/myfirstapp/MyFirstApp/ContentProvider/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
this is another error shown with the error reported above in the title.
i am new to android. can i get the detailed idea ?

Comment: just remove `</ provider >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `</ provider >`

and remove space from `</ application>`.

It should be like `</application>`

Answer (score 0):

You have already closed the `<provider>` tag. No need for `</provider>`.

Comment: as camelCaseCoder has said, you have closed the provider tag already. Refer to the line; android:name="StudentsProvider"/>  The slash (/) closes the provider.